# ¿Cómo evitar en Laravel 5.2 que mi filtro en la paginación, se pierda al cambiar de paginación?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

**Todo funciona bien, es sólo que el resultado que había obtenido y mostrado en el paginate mediante el formulario del search, y al cambiar de página en el paginate, se pierde todo y el paginate se vuelve a llenar con todos los datos.**

> Este es mi index en el controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request)
    {
        $query = trim($request->get('searchText'));
        $locales = DB::table('locales')->where('LocalesNombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                                       ->where('LocalesActivo','=','1')
                                       ->orwhere('LocalesTipo','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                                       ->where('LocalesActivo','=','1')
                                       ->orderBy('LocalesCodigo', 'desc')
                                       ->paginate(7);
        return view('formulario.local.index', ["locales" => $locales, "searchText" => $query]);
    }
}
```

> Este es mi view en index:

```
@extends ('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h3>Listado de Locales <a href="/formulario/local/create"><button class="btn btn-success">Nuevo</button></a></h3>       
        @include('formulario.local.search')
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                    <th>Dirección</th>
                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                    <th>Encomienda</th>
                    <th>Pasajes</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Opciones</th>
                </thead>
               @foreach ($locales as $local)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $local->LocalesCodigo}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $local->LocalesNombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $local->LocalesTipo}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $local->LocalesDireccion}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $local->LocalesTelefono}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if($local->LocalesEncomienda=='0')
                            No
                        @else
                            Si
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if($local->LocalesPasajes=='0')
                            No
                        @else
                            Si
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $local->LocalesColor}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{URL::action('LocalController@edit',$local->LocalesCodigo)}}"><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></a>
                         <a href="" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$local->LocalesCodigo}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @include('formulario.local.modal')
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
        {{$locales->render()}}
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

> En el formulario del search tengo esto:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'formulario/local','method'=>'GET','autocomplete'=>'off','role'=>'search')) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchText" placeholder="Buscar..." value="{{$searchText}}">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
            <a href="/formulario/local" class="btn btn-default">Listar todo</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: Es correcto funciona Ok en laravel 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el método appends antes de renderizar tus links. Para tu ejemplo, sería

```
$locales->appends(['searchText' => $searchText])->links();
```

Saludos

Comment: Graciassss @Cristian, funciona perfecto :)

Answer (score 0):

Probaría a cambiar en la vista:

```
{{$locales->render()}}
```

por:

```
{{$locales->links()}}
```

Comment: Hola @loff, disculpa mi ignorancia; pero en dónde colocarías links() ?

Comment: No sé si funcionará. A mí no me dió ese problema al que haces alusión usando este método.

Comment: Hola @loff, no funciona con links(). Al hacer click en la paginación, se pierde el filtro y se muestra nuevamente todos los registros. :(

Answer (score -1):

Funciona
muy bien , sigue adelante.
En mi caso utilizo 2 variables:

```
{{$tablas1->appends(['searchText' => $searchText, 'cCodTab' => $cCodTab])->links()}}
```

Comment: por favor mira [answer] debes agregar una explicación, además dale formato a tu código eligiendolo y dando click en el ícono `{}` además considera aportar mas detalles pues estas respondiendo a tu pregunta que ya tiene una respuesta aceptada